# calculate percentage of total for multiple columns

Tags: r, tidyverse, percentage, sapply

I have a data-frame in R with several columns that contribute to a totals column, as per below:

```
data <- data_frame(
Date = c("14/12/2018", "15/12/2018", "16/12/2018"),
Ent = c("C1", "C1", "C1"),
Ans = c(4, 9, 12),
Aban = c(1, 2, 1),
OOH = c(7, 5, 6),
Total = c(12, 16, 19),
)
```

Output below:

```
Date       Ent     Ans  Aban   OOH Total
<chr>      <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
14/12/2018 C1        4     1     7    12
15/12/2018 C1        9     2     5    16
16/12/2018 C1       12     1     6    19
```

What I am wanting to do is find the most efficient way that I can calculate the percentage contribution of each column to the total. Below I have my current solution which requires three separate lines of code:

```
#Ans
data$AnsP <- (data$Ans / data$Total) * 100

#Aban
data$AbanP <- (data$Aban / data$Total) * 100

#OOH
data$OOHP <- (data$OOH / data$Total) * 100
```

However, as I anticipate the source data-set to grow, this will eventually become sub-optimal for multiple variables

Is there an easy way I can calculate these percentage contributions in a single line of code, returning these percentages as columns in the existing dataframe? Perhaps with sapply or a function? I have made some crude attempts, but they have not worked

Desire Output as a dataframe:

```
Date       Ent     Ans  Aban   OOH Total  AnsP AbanP  OOHP
<chr>      <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
14/12/2018 C1        4     1     7    12  33.3  8.33  58.3
15/12/2018 C1        9     2     5    16  56.2 12.5   31.2
16/12/2018 C1       12     1     6    19  63.2  5.26  31.6
```

Any assistance would be appreciated on this

Regards,
Tom

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)

data %>%
   mutate_at(vars(Ans:OOH) , funs(P = ./data$Total * 100))


#   Date       Ent     Ans  Aban   OOH Total Ans_P Aban_P OOH_P
#  <chr>      <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
#1 14/12/2018 C1        4     1     7    12  33.3   8.33  58.3
#2 15/12/2018 C1        9     2     5    16  56.2  12.5   31.2
#3 16/12/2018 C1       12     1     6    19  63.2   5.26  31.6
```

---

Or if you prefer base R

```
cols <- 3:5
cbind(data, data[cols]/data$Total * 100)
```

As `Total` column is same as sum of `cols` column we could also do

```
data[cols]/rowSums(data[cols]) * 100
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response Ronak. Your responses are elegant solutions to my initial query, but my source data has a few other quirks I did not mention. I have edited my post to reflect these quirks, which are an additional character variable, and different variable names for our columns we would like to calculate a percentage for. As such, the tidyverse solution did not work on account of the variable names. Your base R solution worked on my data here, but in my target data, returned a list, or an error "number of rows of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 2)"

Comment: Is there a tidyverse solution that does not rely on the 'starts_with' function, so I can specify ans, aban & ooh?

Comment: @perkot I have updated the answer based on your edit. You can specifically give range of columns using `:` . I have used `Ans:OOH` here. Also the base R solutions should work fine, you just need to adjust  `cols` according to the columns for which you want to calculate.

Comment: thanks again. Your solution works on my mock-data. On my source data, it is returning an error : "Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Column `Abandoned_P` must be length 1 (the group size), not 496". I have 496 rows, and the first column is 'Abandoned'. I have appended your solution to my source data.  I'm not sure why this would be the case as it is a dataframe, all relevant variables numeric. The only obvious difference is I am calculating the percentage of 5 columns

Comment: @perkot Are you doing some `group_by` operation before applying the solution? it would be difficult to find out why it is not working on actual data since it works on sample data. Can you try the base R option? Remember `cols` should include all the columns for which you want to calculate the percentage. So if it is first 5 columns, `cols` should be `1:5`. I have used `3:5` here because we wanted to calculated percentage for those column numbers.

Comment: I had completed a group_by function to create this source table - I am wondering if that is in some way effecting this solution? I will try the base r solution later when I get home. Thanks again for your assistance so far

Comment: @perkot yep. If you previously performed a `group_by` operation it would impact this operation. First do `ungroup` and then apply the function. So do, `data %>% ungroup() %>%
   mutate_at(vars(Ans:OOH) , funs(P = ./data$Total * 100))
`

Comment: Wonderful! I will try this in a couple of hours and let you know how it went :) thanks again, Tom

Comment: Hi again Ronak - the updated dplyr solution that ungroups the df first worked perfectly. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 3):

We can use `data.table` to assign in place

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)[, paste0(names(data)[3:5], '_P') := lapply(.SD, function(x) 
        x/Total * 100), .SDcols = 3:5]
data
#         Date Ent Ans Aban OOH Total    Ans_P    Aban_P    OOH_P
#1: 14/12/2018  C1   4    1   7    12 33.33333  8.333333 58.33333
#2: 15/12/2018  C1   9    2   5    16 56.25000 12.500000 31.25000
#3: 16/12/2018  C1  12    1   6    19 63.15789  5.263158 31.57895
```

Comment: Hi Akrun - thank you for your response, this has also answered my questions. Regards, Tom